# Help me write a correct title for my article!

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I’m writing an article about "online jobs" for my English class. I wrote a title for that, but I’d like you to tell me if it makes sense to you or is that grammatically correct?

Please feel free to give more idea.

> • You don't have to go outside to make money, instead, learn how to make money online from home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title is clear, but the punctuation is incorrect. **Instead** is not a conjunction. It is an adverb. It cannot be used to join ideas on the same side of a period or a semicolon. You have two options if you want to correct the  punctuation:

> 1. You don't have to go outside to make money. Instead, learn how to make money online from home.
> 2. You don't have to go outside to make money; instead, learn how to make money online from home.

But either version is wordy for a title. Consider shortening it to something like this:

> How to Make Money Online from Home

Comment: As some people find semi-colons difficult, here is a quick explanation: You use a semi-colon (;) when joining 2 short sentences **with a related topic**.